# ソースコードリーディングについて

Tags: c

最近, プログラミング言語を勉強し始めまして, pythonとrubyに興味を持ちました。

その言語自体のソースコードを見てみると, C言語で記述されているのが分かったのですが, 多くのファイルから成っていることが分かり, 途端に複雑さが増して混乱しています。

こういった大きなプロジェクトのソースコードリーディングのやり方を教えてください。

Comment: こんにちは。たぶん質問自体は良いものだと感じるのですが、スタックオーバフローでは質問する前に「ある程度の下調べ」をしてから質問するというのが公式のルールのようです。この質問は @soramaru さんがどのような問題に直面したのかはわかるのですが、それにたいしてどのような努力や調査を行い、そしてどこでつまずいたのか、それがあまりにも不透明なため、低評価が付いているのだと思います。「こういった大きなプロジェクトのソースコードリーディングのやり方を教えてください」だと、回答者としても質問があまりにもざっくりとしすぎて回答しにくさを感じます。もうすこし具体的にどのようなプロジェクトで詰まっているのか、そしてできるだけ詳細に書いていただけると回答者としても回答がしやすくなります。

Comment: Rubyなら、まず「[Rubyソースコード完全解説 : 青木 峰郎, まつもと ゆきひろ](http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/4844317210)」を読むとか。古いですけど。

Comment: この質問には「質問の範囲が広すぎる」という理由でクローズ票が投じられています。 いちどSOの[ガイドライン](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)をお読みになって 質問の範囲を狭められないか 検討してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

プログラムにはいろいろな種類がありますが、その中でもコンパイラやインタプリタといった言語処理系は特に複雑な部類に入りますので、そのソースコードを読むのも難易度が高くなります。処理する側(例えばC)と処理される側(RubyやPython)両方の知識が必要な上、構文解析などコンピュータ科学の幅広い知識も必要です。

RubyやPythonで(または言語は問わずに)プログラムを書くのが目的なのであれば処理系自身のソースコードが読めることは必須ではありません。それぞれの言語の入門書やなどで勉強されるとよいでしょう。

RubyやPythonがどのように動いているかという言語処理系としての仕組みが知りたいということであれば、まずCと対象の言語をしっかり習得する必要があります。さらに言語処理の仕組みについては専門書で学習する事になるでしょう。

Cを勉強するためにソースリーディングをやっているのであれば、言語処理系は難易度が高すぎる題材だと思います。もっと小規模なものから挑戦した方がよいでしょう。それにしても、そのプログラムが何をしているのかの知識は必要になります。